# How to interpret "many"

Tags: meaning

> The island has many events, cafes, museums and even its own outdoor
>   theatre!

Which interpretation is correct for the example above?

The island has many events, many cafes, and many museums, and there is even its own outdoor theatre!

or

The island has many events, many cafes, many museums, and a lot of its own outdoor theatre!

Is the interpretation context-dependent?

Comment: Where is this sentence from?  It is kind of ill-formed, in that the possessive "its" in the last clause doesn't match the lack of possessive at the beginning of the sentence.

Comment: @CanadianYankee I just edited the sentence!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Words like ***many***, indeed a lot of adjectives, can distribute over lists - in this case, as long as the list is all plural things or, sometimes, mass nouns, it applies to those. Once the list gets to a singular thing, it stops applying. You can generalise this for other adjectives as it applying until it would make no sense or would be grammatically invalid (though sometimes people do use it even when it becomes a little grammatically invalid, like *many* for a mass noun). Thus, your first interpretation is the correct one.